# How to put viewpager inside fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I've an activity and I can show some fragments on framelayout on this activity.
I would like to put a viewpager made up of fragments inside a fragment instead of a FragmentActivity. How can this be done?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To have a `ViewPager` be in a fragment, and to have fragments be the pages in that `ViewPager`, you need to use nested fragments. If your `minSdkVersion` is 17 or higher, the native implementation of fragments supports nested fragments. Otherwise, you will need to use the `support-v13` (or `support-v4`) backport of fragments.

Then, you just need to give `getChildFragmentManager()` to your `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.pagernested;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    return(result);
  }

  private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested))

Comment: Previously I used `getFragmentManager()`. Then changed by `getChildFragmentManager()`. Worked like a charm!

Comment: What is best approach to send data to nested fragment(viewpager's fragment)  from host fragment?

Comment: @ZaidMirza: If possible, I would used a shared `ViewModel`.

Comment: Yes that would be best but Unfortunately on going project have not Implemented MVVM. But I guess we can still use ViewModel for this purpose even its not MVVM

Comment: @ZaidMirza: The Jetpack `ViewModel` class is not strictly related to MVVM. Many of my book examples that use `ViewModel` employ something more akin to MVI, for example. I really wish that they had not used "ViewModel" as the name, but they didn't ask me. :-)